# How to create a variable for a SKSpriteNode that was created in a while loop, for the purpose of checking the sprite for a touch

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have created 20 sprites using a while loop. All of these sprites are children of an SKNode called "*centerNode*". Each sprite has a name one number off (0-19 are the twenty names). Each sprite has a unique anchorPoint that differs in the x-Axis. When I run the application with just this code:

```
    var centerNode = SKNode()



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

centerNode = self.childNode(withName: "centerNode")!

    var x = 0.0

           while x < 20 {

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode()
        sprite.name = "\(x)"
        sprite.size = CGSize(width: 295, height: 100)
        sprite.color = UIColor.lightGray
        sprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 2.0 - 2 * x, y: 3)
        sprite.zPosition = 2
        centerNode.addChild(sprite)
        x = x + 1
    }
```

twenty sprites appear in a row (Exactly how I set them). I want to be able to test when the sprite with the name "0" is touched, but I am unable to since whenever I create a variable using

```
let zero = self.childNode(withName: "0")
```

or

```
let zero = centerNode.childNode(withName: "0")
```

or

```
let zero = self.childNode(withName: "0") as! SKSpriteNode
```

or

```
let zero = centerNode.childNode(withName: "0") as! SKSpriteNode
```

all of these result in this Error:

"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

This to me signals that the sprites have either not been created with their names by my code as I wanted them or my variable is looking in the wrong place for the SKSpriteNode. Both of those would return nil when the variable is initialized. I have initialized the variable in different functions to make sure that it wasnt initializing the var before the sprites were created this does not seem to be the problem.

I want to be able to run:

```
if zero.containsPoint(locationOfTouch) {
//then do this
{
```

but I can not get a variable to work with the SKSpriteNodes

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "x" variable is float, so probably your names are look like "0.0","1.0"...
Change this code: `var x = 0.0` to var `x:Int = 0`
And probably you will have to change your anchor point code to this:

```
sprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 2.0 - 2 * CGFloat(x), y: 3)
```

Comment: I wouldn't even use a while loop.  use a for loop to avoid having the code get too ugly